# The equivalence of Euclidean norm and finite element norm in 3D for non-uniform meshes

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

I am interested in equivalence between Euclidean norm and finite element norm: 
$$ C_0\left\| \mathbf{v}^h \right\|_2 \leq \left\| P^h\mathbf{v}^h \right\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C_1\left\| \mathbf{v}^h \right\|_2 $$

My question is related to previously posted question: 
The equivalence of Euclidean norm and finite element norm
[The equivalence of Euclidean norm and finite element norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493912/the-equivalence-of-euclidean-norm-and-finite-element-norm)

I am mostly interested in knowing what needs to be adjusted, such that proof holds also in 3D and for non-uniform finite elements(still P1, Lagrange).